# MySQL Find the model number of the highest priced product.

Tags: mysql

Relations:

```
Product(maker, model, type) 
Laptop(Model, price, speed, ram, hd, screen) 
PC(model, price, speed, ram, hd) 
Printer(model,price, color, price)
```

I am trying to find the model number of the product with the highest price.

What I have tried:

```
-> SELECT model, MAX(price) FROM
-> ((SELECT model, MAX(price) FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc)
-> union
-> (SELECT model, MAX(price) FROM product NATURAL JOIN printer)
-> union
-> (SELECT model, MAX(price) FROM product NATURAL JOIN laptop));
```

The error I keep getting is "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the max() functions in the subselects:

```
SELECT model, MAX(price)
FROM (
   SELECT model, MAX(price) AS price ...
                           ^^^^^^^^^
   etc...
```

You're basically creating a table on the fly with the subqueries, so tecnically the outer query would have to be

```
SELECT model, MAX(MAX(price))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^--- field name in subselects
```

which won't really work. you're doing a double MAX() call on a field name (price) which is not returned from the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

That query won't work. I think this is what you're looking for given you query:

```
(SELECT model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc)
union all
(SELECT model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN printer)
union all
(SELECT model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN laptop)
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Edit:** Expanding answer based on your comment

Well, the previous query results in one tuple. If you meant just one field/attribute/column then you should do:

```
SELECT model from (
    (SELECT model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN pc)
    union all
    (SELECT model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN printer)
    union all
    (SELECT model, price FROM product NATURAL JOIN laptop)
) final
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But this will be slower, and probably unnecesary.

I didn't get the `where price < all`. If you order by price desc and only get the first record you'll only get the highest priced record.

Comment: I am trying to return just one relation with one tuple, which has the model number of the highest priced product. So could I take this query above, encapsulate it in () and then do a SELECT model FROM [query above] WHERE price < all; ?